# Pattern match with Table for matrix dimension check

Tags: programming, matrix, syntax, symbolic

In Mathematica, often an expression involving matrices will encounter dimension mismatch errors, like we are multiplying a 3x2 matrix to a 3x4 matrix. Below we define a new symbol Dim, which can be passed through your algorithm as a fake parameter to detect errors.

```
Dim /: Dot[Dim[{x_, y_}], z_] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[y, Dimensions[z][[1]]];
   Dim[{x, Dimensions[z][[2]]}]);
```

This method can handle most matrix operations, but failed on Table, which seems quite special. In fact, I failed to pattern match with Table by writing:

```
Dim /: Times[Dim[{x_, y_}], Table[z_]] := Dim[x, y];(*incorrect, just for syntax*)
Dim /: Times[Table[z_], Dim[{x_, y_}]] := Dim[x, y];
```

The expected result should be:

```
Dim[{3, 2}] Table[Sin[i + j], {i, 3}, {j, 2}] == Dim[{3, 2}]
```

But now Dim is multiplied over every element of table and it returns:

```
{{Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[2], Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[3]}, {Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[3], Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[4]}, {Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[4], Dim[{3, 2}] Sin[5]}} == Dim[{3, 2}]
```

Full code:

```
Clear[Dim];
checkEq =
  Function[{x, y},
   If[x != y, Print[ToString[x] <> "!=" <> ToString[y]]; Abort[]]];
Dim /: Dimensions[Dim[x_]] := x;
Dim /: MatrixQ[Dim[_]] := True;
Dim /: Dot[Dim[{x_, y_}], z_] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[y, Dimensions[z][[1]]];
   Dim[{x, Dimensions[z][[2]]}]);
Dim /: Dot[z_, Dim[{x_, y_}]] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[Dimensions[z][[2]], x];
   Dim[{Dimensions[z][[1]], y}]);
Dim /: Times[z_, Dim[{x_, y_}]] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[Dimensions[z], {x, y}]; Dim[{x, y}]);
Dim /: Times[Dim[{x_, y_}], z_] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[Dimensions[z], {x, y}]; Dim[{x, y}]);
Dim /: Plus[z_, Dim[{x_, y_}]] /;
   MatrixQ[z] :=
  (checkEq[Dimensions[z], {x, y}]; Dim[{x, y}]);
(*Dim/:Dot[Dim[{x_,y_}],Dim[{z_,w_}]]:=(checkEq[y,z];Dim[{x,w}]);
Dim/:Times[Dim[{x_,y_}],Dim[{z_,w_}]]:=(checkEq[x,z];checkEq[y,w];Dim[{x,y}]);\
Dim/:Plus[Dim[{x_,y_}],Dim[{z_,w_}]]:=(checkEq[x,z];checkEq[y,w];Dim[{x,y}]);*)
Dim /: Times[x_, Dim[{y_, z_}]] /; NumberQ[x] := Dim[{y, z}];

(*Below are tests that should return true.*)
MatrixQ[Dim[{2, 3}]]
Dimensions@Dim[{1, 2}] == {1, 2}
Dim[{3, 2}].Dim[{2, 4}] == Dim[{3, 4}]
Dim[{3, 2}].RandomReal[1, {2, 4}] == Dim[{3, 4}]
RandomReal[1, {2, 4}].Dim[{4, 3}] == Dim[{2, 3}]
Dim[{3, 2}] Dim[{3, 2}] == Dim[{3, 2}]
2 Dim[{3, 2}] == Dim[{3, 2}]
Dim[{3, 2}] - Dim[{3, 2}] == Dim[{3, 2}]

(*Below are tests that should raise errors.*)
Dim[{3, 2}] - Dim[{2, 4}]
Dim[{3, 2}] Dim[{2, 4}]
Dim[{5, 3}].Dim[{2, 4}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what underlying problem you're trying to solve here, let alone why this particular approach is being used... That said, Table[z_] expressions in code seem to be where your problem is... If you're trying to match a 'list of lists' that can be done; if you're trying to match an expression with the Head 'Table', that too can be done, although evaluation control will probably be needed. Advice: do some prototyping with MatchQ. This will force you to make explicit what you're trying to match, and will enable you to identify what will work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have an evaluation order problem.  I suspect that you are unaware of the order of evaluation regarding UpValues definitions.  Allow me to give a few illustrations.

I'll make a generic UpValue rule using `UpSetDelayed`:

```
_[___, up[1], ___] ^:= "one"
```

Arguments are evaluated before UpValues rules are triggered, unless the function has a Hold attribute such as `HoldAll`:

```
List[Print[1 + 1], up[1], Print[2 + 2]]
```

> 2
>
> 4
>
> ```
> "one"
> ```

For this reason your `Table` is evaluated before your `Dim` rule is checked.  Perhaps the most direct way around this is to use `Unevaluated` for every instance of `Table`.  Using a simplified rule:

```
dim /: Times[dim[], _Table] := "Table found"

Times[dim[], Table[x[n], {n, 5}]] (* this doesn't match *)
```

> ```
> {dim[] x[1], dim[] x[2], dim[] x[3], dim[] x[4], dim[] x[5]}
> ```

```
Times[dim[], Unevaluated @ Table[x[n], {n, 5}]] (* this does *)
```

> ```
> "Table found"
> ```

Of course this isn't very convenient.

I must admit I don't understand how you are intending to use `Dims` and why you don't merely check the data with `Dimensions`.  If you explain that perhaps I can suggest a different implementation.

Comment: +1, for taking the time to figure out something helpful to say.